# Setting cell.textLabel.text with NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, nsdictionary

How do I reference the NSDictionary *fbFriends I created below

```
[FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *me = (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *)result;
                    // Store the Facebook Id
                    [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:me.objectID forKey:@"fbId"];
                    [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];

                    // 1
                    FBRequest *friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"/me/friends"];
                    [friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                                  NSDictionary* result,
                                                                  NSError *error) {
                        // 2
                        NSArray *friends = result[@"data"];
                        for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
                            NSLog(@"Found a friend: %@", friend.name);
                            // 3
                            // Add the friend to the list of friends in the DataStore
                            [[DataStore instance].fbFriends setObject:friend forKey:friend.objectID];
                        }

                        // 4
                        // Callback - login successful
                        if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(commsDidLogin:)]) {
                            [delegate commsDidLogin:YES];
                        }
                    }];


                    // Add the User to the list of friends in the DataStore
                    [[DataStore instance].fbFriends setObject:me forKey:me.objectID];
                }
            }];
```

In DataStore.h I have

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *fbFriends;
```

I've been trying to reference it several ways but nothing is working. I don't know what key I am supposed to used
in my tableviewcontroller

```
cell.textLabel.text=[[DataStore instance].fbFriends objectForKey:self];
```

I want to list the names of your fb friends that also use the app. My NSLog shows that I have friends but I don't know how to display them in the table view controller cell

I'm using code from Ray Wenderlichs tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/44833/integrating-facebook-and-parse-tutorial-part-2

Here is an NSLog of the dictionary

```
Dictionary contents: {
    10152183401605823 =     {
        id = 10152183401605823;
        name = "John Gor";
    };
    10203978226397607 =     {
        "first_name" = Katie;
        gender = female;
        id = 10237890226397607;
        "last_name" = James;
        link = "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/10237890226397607/";
        locale = "en_US";
        name = "Katie James";
        timezone = "-5";
        "updated_time" = "2013-12-22T16:18:07+0000";
        verified = 1;
    };
```

Comment: Please explain what the "several ways" you tried were.

Comment: I replaced `self` with a lot of different possible options like `[DataStore instance].fbFriends` or `@"id"` `@"fbId"` and other things i can think of that might be the key. this is my first app so I'm trying to use tutorials but since xcode 5 a lot of the stuff doesn't work anymore

Comment: the code says `setObject:friend forKey:friend.objectID` but idk how to interpret that to use it to set the text for my cells

Comment: You don't need to guess what the key is: the key is whatever `friend.objectID` is.

Comment: how do I find that out? i tried `@"friend.objectID"` but that didn't produce anything. When i remove the @ and quotes i get "Use of undeclared identifier" for friend.

Comment: Trying random lines of code in the hope that they work is kind of like sticking random computer chips in a case and hoping it turns into a working computer. The two have about the same likelihood of success. You need to think through what you are trying to do, and then figure out how to write the code that does that. I see 3 or 4 ways your code is confused and wrong that tell me that you are in completely over your head. Perhaps it's time to do some studying before you try to write an app?

Comment: I'm definitely in over my head and old tutorials have really made learning much more difficult but what I'm trying to do is the foundation for a much simpler app, it's just that managing users is not an easy thing to wrap your head around with no good up to date example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things:

The code you posted calls `[[DataStore instance].fbFriends setObject: <some_value>];`

That will only work if you have created an empty dictionary and saved it in your data store's fbFriends property at some point. Declaring the property is not enough, you have to allocate an empty dictionary somewhere, using new, dictionaryWithCapacity, alloc/init, or similar.

This code:

```
cell.textLabel.text=[[DataStore instance].fbFriends objectForKey:self];
```

Makes no sense. Why would you use "self" as a key to your fbFriends array? Self is presumably the view controller. Using a view controller as a key to a dictionary is wrong.

What key/value pairs do you expect to find in your dictionary?

You have to know what data is stored in a dictionary before you can fetch key/vaue pairs from it. Have you logged the contents of your dictionary? The code might look something like this:

```
NSLog(@"Dictionary contents: %@", [DataStore instance].fbFriends);
```

It looks to me like fbFriends is a dictionary of friend objects (which are also dictionaries) stored with the friend ID as the key for each entry in fbFriends. Thus, even if you were able to load a friend object from fbFriends, you would not be able to assign an entry from fbFriends to your label text.

What are you trying to display in the label text of your table view?

Also, your fbFriends are a dictionary. Dictionaries are not ordered, so they are not suitable for feeding a table view.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer Duncan. Running the NSLog you suggested does produce the contents of the dictionary. The `self` code is just the only thing i could come up with not to produce an error. Idk how to reference my dictionary key from my tableviewcontroller.

Comment: I added the dictionary log to the question if you could check it out real quick

Comment: Yes, you have a dictionary that contains dictionaries. You can't use a dictionary as a data source for a table view because dictionaries are unordered collections (their contents are not in any particular order.) You need to refactor your code to save your items in an array, not a dictionary. An array of dictionaries would be fine.